# Execute copy from command from plsq

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g

How to execute copy from command inside a plsql block?

E.g. I have `copy from test/test@test insert emp using select * from emp;`

How can I call this in a plsql block? I have tried with

```
execute immediate 'copy from test/test@test insert emp using select * from emp';
```

However when I execute my script which has plsql block gives me

```
ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement
```

How can I resolve this issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

COPY is a SQL*Plus command.  So it only works in the SQL*Plus client.  [Find out more.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a90842/apb.htm)

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE is a PL/SQL command to run dynamic calls, and it only recognises SQL and PL/SQL.

> "I am executing sqlscript from sqlplus"

Yes, but you are calling COPY in an anonymous block, so that's with a PL/SQL scope; which means PL/SQL and SQL only.

The way to do this is with a shell script.  These are operating system dependent, but something like this would work on a Linux environment.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo Please enter local Username:
read USERNAME

echo "Please enter local Password:"
read -s PASS   

SID=${ORACLE_SID}

if [ "${ORACLE_SID}" != 'TEST'  ]
then
    sqlplus -s -l $USERNAME/$PASS@$SID  << EOF
    copy from test/test@test insert emp using select * from emp
    exit
EOF

else
    echo  "Can't copy from TEST to TEST"
fi
```

Obviously this is just a wild guess at what your program actually does, but I hope you can understand the principle.

Comment: I have a sqlscript which has anonymous plsql block and inside that I have if condition which checks the instance name, if it is matching, then I would like to transfer data from one database to another and hence I am using `copy from` command. I can execute enable and disable triggers inside plsql block using `execute immediate`, however I am not able use `copy from` command using `execute immediate`. I am executing sqlscript from `sqlplus`.

Comment: Thanks APC, this really helped. Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In a plsql code if we directly use the command as follows shall serve the similar output

```
begin
  insert into emp1 select * from emp;
end;
```

emp1 is target table
emp is source table

Answer (score 0):

There are similar ask where one wants to create blank structure or structure with data for backup kindly of activity.Refer link https://oracle-concepts-learning.blogspot.com/2019/09/copy-table-structure-or-data.html

1) Creating blank structure from existing table

--Execute on sql prompt

```
begin
  execute immediate 'create table emp1 as select * from emp where 1=2';
end;
```

--Execute on sql prompt
    select count(1) from emp1;

2) Creating structure from existing table with data

--Execute on sql prompt
    begin
      execute immediate 'create table emp1 as select * from emp';
    end;

--Execute on sql prompt

```
select count(1) from emp1;
```